# Setup to develop Aurelia using SystemJS and transpile ts files on browser?

Tags: file, browser, server, aurelia, transpiler

First of all, my case is quite unusual, so let me explain:

Our product runs on a local self-made server (for example, `http://localhost:1234/`). The same server serve the UI files (`http://localhost:1234/index.html`) and CANNOT add CORS header.

Now my Aurelia app will need to access data from the same origin, but during development, this is not possible with Aurelia CLI because the server of Aurelia would be running on another port, and moreover, our request is intended to be without hostname (`/request/data`).

This is my desired solution: Use SystemJS to transpile the `.ts` files on browser side during development. For now, I have to build (`au build`) every time I have a small change and it's very inconvenient.

Please tell me how to config/setup to transpile project created from Aurelia CLI on browser side.

Comment: You are not using `au run --watch`? I don't understand why you need to do `au build` every time.

Comment: @huocp `au run --watch` will run the server on another port (usually `http://localhost:8080`) and the index page would be `http://localhost:8080`. However, I need it served from `http://localhost:1234` (and the 1234 port is already occupied by the backend server)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run your front-end dev "linking" to another backend server.

You don't have to play with SystemJS directly, I have a setup to run my dev front-end dev against specified backend server (local or remote).

This is a cli+requirejs (or cli+systemjs) setup.

I always want to write a tutorial on how to do this, but didn't find enough spare time.

**Here is the crash course.**

I use `http-proxy-middleware` in `aurelia_project/tasks/run.js` to hook up backend. Read my code, there is default backend url, and you can overwrite it in command line. **Note it supports http/https, you can do your dev work against your production app, very useful in bug hunting.**

```
au run --watch --backend http(s)://other.domain:optional_port
```

There are two part you need to change.

1. the list of proxied urls (after `const backendProxy = proxy([`),
   these are urls you want to pass the request to backend server.
2. the list of bypasses for historyApiFallback. You need to read the
   doc of connect-history-api-fallback to understand how it works.
   Basically, connect-history-api-fallback tries to catch some requests
   and return same index.html to support SPA dev. You need to bypass
   some request to next middleware on the chain.

My full run.js.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback/lib';
import {CLIOptions} from 'aurelia-cli';
import project from '../aurelia.json';
import build from './build';
import watch from './watch';
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const backend = CLIOptions.getFlagValue('backend') || 'https://localhost:8443';
const isHttps = !!backend.match(/^https/);

const backendProxy = proxy([
  '**/WSFed/**',
  '**/log*',
  '**/login/**',
  '**/logout/**',
  '**/logoff/**',
  '**/assets/**',
  '**/images/**',
  '**/*.json',
  '**/*download*/**',
  '**/*download*',
  '**/leavingAnalytics'
], {
  target: backend,
  // logLevel: 'debug',
  changeOrigin: true,
  secure: false, // bypass certificate check
  autoRewrite: true,
  // hostRewrite: true,
  protocolRewrite: isHttps ? 'https' : 'http'
  // onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
  //   console.log('proxyRes headers: '+ JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers));
  // }
});

function passThrough(context) {
  return context.parsedUrl.pathname;
}

function bypass(regex) {
  return {
    from: regex,
    to: passThrough
  };
}

let serve = gulp.series(
  build,
  done => {
    browserSync({
      ghostMode: false,
      reloadDebounce: 2000,
      https: isHttps,
      online: false,
      open: CLIOptions.hasFlag('open'),
      port: 9000,
      // logLevel: 'debug',
      logLevel: 'silent',
      server: {
        baseDir: [project.platform.baseDir],
        middleware: [
          historyApiFallback({
            // verbose: true,
            rewrites: [
              {from: /azure\/authorize/, to: '/index.html'},
              bypass(/\/WFFed\//),
              bypass(/\/login/),
              bypass(/\/logout/),
              bypass(/\/logoff/),
              bypass(/\/assets/),
              bypass(/ajax/),
              bypass(/download/),
              bypass(/leavingAnalytics/)
            ]
          }),
          function(req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            next();
          },
          backendProxy
        ]
      }
    }, function(err, bs) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      let urls = bs.options.get('urls').toJS();
      log(`Application Available At: ${urls.local}`);
      log(`BrowserSync Available At: ${urls.ui}`);
      done();
    });
  }
);

function log(message) {
  console.log(message); //eslint-disable-line no-console
}

function reload() {
  log('Refreshing the browser');
  browserSync.reload();
}

let run;

if (CLIOptions.hasFlag('watch')) {
  run = gulp.series(
    serve,
    done => { watch(reload); done(); }
  );
} else {
  run = serve;
}

export default run;
```

Comment: Ok I got the principle, look like it can solve my problem. Will try this and report the result soon. Thank you very much!